# MySQL Indexes for extremely slow queries

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

The following query, regardless of environment, takes more than 30 seconds to compute.

```
SELECT COUNT( r.response_answer ) 
FROM response r
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT G.question_id
 FROM question G
 INNER JOIN answer_group AG ON G.answer_group_id = AG.answer_group_id
 WHERE AG.answer_group_stat =  'statistic'
) AS q ON r.question_id = q.question_id
INNER JOIN org_survey os ON os.org_survey_code = r.org_survey_code
WHERE os.survey_id =42
AND r.response_answer = 5
AND DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , r.added_dt ) <1000000
AND r.uuid IS NOT NULL
```

When I explain the query,

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1087     
1   PRIMARY r   ref question_id,org_survey_code,code_question,uuid,uor question_id  4   q.question_id   1545    Using where
1   PRIMARY os  eq_ref  org_survey_code,survey_id,org_survey_code_2 org_survey_code 12  survey_2.r.org_survey_code  1   Using where
2   DERIVED G   ALL agid    NULL    NULL    NULL    1680     
2   DERIVED AG  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1   survey_2.G.answer_group_id    1 Using where
```

I have a very basic knowledge of indexing, but I have tried nearly every combination I can think of and cannot seem to improve the speed of this query.  The responses table is right around 2 million rows, question is about 1500 rows, answer_group is about 50, and org_survey is about 8,000.

Here is the basic structure for each:

```
CREATE TABLE `response` (
 `response_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `response_answer` text NOT NULL,
 `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `org_survey_code` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `uuid` varchar(40) default NULL,
 `added_dt` datetime default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`response_id`),
 KEY `question_id` (`question_id`),
 KEY `org_survey_code` (`org_survey_code`),
 KEY `code_question` (`org_survey_code`,`question_id`),
 KEY `IDX_ADDED_DT` (`added_dt`),
 KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
 KEY `response_answer` (`response_answer`(1)),
 KEY `response_question` (`response_answer`(1),`question_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2298109 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `question` (
 `question_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `question_text` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
 `question_group` varchar(250) default NULL,
 `question_position` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `survey_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `answer_group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `seq_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`question_id`),
 KEY `question_group` (`question_group`(10)),
 KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),
 KEY `agid` (`answer_group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1860 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `org_survey` (
 `org_survey_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `org_survey_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
 `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `org_manager_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `org_url_id` int(11) default '0',
 `division_id` int(11) default '0',
 `sector_id` int(11) default NULL,
 `survey_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `process_batch` tinyint(4) default '0',
 `added_dt` datetime default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`org_survey_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `org_survey_code` (`org_survey_code`),
 KEY `org_id` (`org_id`),
 KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),
 KEY `org_survey_code_2` (`org_survey_code`,`total_taken`),
 KEY `org_manager_id` (`org_manager_id`),
 KEY `sector_id` (`sector_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9268 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `answer_group` (
 `answer_group_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `answer_group_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
 `answer_group_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
 `answer_group_stat` varchar(20) NOT NULL default 'demographic',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`answer_group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I know there are small things I can probably do to improve the efficiency of the database, such as reducing the size of integers where it's unnecessary.  However, those are fairly trivial considering the ridiculous time it takes just to produce a result here.  How can I properly index these tables, based on what explain has shown me? It seems that I have tried a large variety of combinations to no avail.  Also, is there anything else that anyone can see that will optimize the table and reduce the query? I need it to be computed in less than a second.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

1.If you want the index of `r.added_dt` to be used, instead of:

```
DATEDIFF(NOW(), r.added_dt) < 1000000
```

use:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1000000 DAY < r.added_dt
```

Anyway, the above condition is checking if `added_at` is **a million days old** or not. Do you really store so old dates? If not, you can simply remove this condition.

If you want this condition, an index on `added_at` would help a lot. Your query as it is now, checks all rows for this condition, calling the `DATEDIFF()` function as many times as the rows of the `response` table.

---

2.Since `r.response_answer` cannot be `NULL`, instead of:

```
SELECT COUNT( r.response_answer )
```

use:

```
SELECT COUNT( * )
```

`COUNT(*)` is faster than `COUNT(field)`.

---

3.Two of the three fields that you use for joining tables have different datatypes:

```
ON       question . answer_group_id 
   = answer_group . answer_group_id

CREATE TABLE question (
  ...
  answer_group_id mediumint(8) ...,               <--- mediumint

CREATE TABLE answer_group (
  answer_group_id` tinyint(3)  ...,               <--- tinyint

-------------------------------

ON org_survey . org_survey_code 
   = response . org_survey_code

CREATE TABLE response (
  ...
  org_survey_code varchar(7) NOT NULL,               <--- 7

CREATE TABLE org_survey (
  ...
  org_survey_code varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',   <--- 10
```

Datatype `mediumint` is not the same as `tinyint` and the same goes for `varchar(7)` and `varchar(10)`. When they are used for join, MySQL has to lose time doing conversion from one type to another. Convert one of them so they have identical datatypes. This is not the main issue of the query but this change will also help all other queries that use these joins.

And after making this change do a 'Analyze Table ' for the table. It will help mysql making better execution plans.

---

You have a `response_answer = 5` condition, where `response_answer` is `text`. It's not an error, but it's better to use `response_answer = '5'` (the conversion of `5` to `'5'` will be done by MySQL anyway, if you don't do that).

Real issue is that you don't have a compound index on the 3 fields that are used in the `WHERE` conditions. Try adding this one:

```
ALTER TABLE response 
  ADD INDEX ind_u1_ra1_aa
      (uuid(1), response_answer(1), added_at) ;
```

(this may take a while as your table is not small)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following query? I've removed the sub-query from your original one. This may let the optimiser produce a better execution plan.

```
SELECT COUNT(r.response_answer) 
FROM response r
    INNER JOIN question q      ON r.question_id = q.question_id
    INNER JOIN answer_group ag ON q.answer_group_id = ag.answer_group_id
    INNER JOIN org_survey os   ON os.org_survey_code = r.org_survey_code
WHERE 
      ag.answer_group_stat =  'statistic'
  AND os.survey_id = 42
  AND r.response_answer = 5
  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), r.added_dt) < 1000000
  AND r.uuid IS NOT NULL
```